# Is there any extension for Google Chrome that would let me use the find function (CTRL+F) over multiple tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, find

Say I had two tabs open and I wanted to search for the term "my term", I would like to view the results from both tabs. I've looked at the chrome extension website ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/find ) and I've searched on Googlebut couldn't find such an extension. It seems like an obvious extension so I assume it must be impossible due to Chrome's design (each tab being a separate process causing the problem maybe?).

Two questions:
1. Is there already an extension for finding text over multiple tabs?
2. Is it technically possible to build such an extension given Chrome's design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Chrome extension named ["Search Plus"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cdpohbejnbclggljmoijjcpdhbaaijfm)

It supports search over all tabs.

The UI also allows to search in only some selected tabs, instead of all, which can be quite useful.